# How can the folder of a user account under c:\users be delete when delete windows account?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to programmatically delete windows accounts along with their corresponding folders under `c:\Users` in `windows 2008R2`.
I call `net user [user name] /delete` command in the program but it does not delete the folder "user name" under `c:\users`. The `DelectFile` function does not work: error code is `5`.

Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried a shell execute of "del /s C:\Users\whatever" instead?

Comment: 5 is *access denied* so the user thats running deletefile lacks sufficient permissions

Comment: @AlexK.: in this case the access denied message is because you're not allowed to do certain file-specific operations (including DeleteFile) on a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just DeleteFile a directory.  You have to explicitly iterate through the contents of the directory, deleting each file and removing each subdirectory.

Also, be warned that the name of the user profile folder is not always identical to the username.  The mapping is stored in the registry somewhere.

Comment: it looks like DeleteFile only works on a "File" or an empty "directory". Now I use "SHFileOperation" instead and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 5 means "access denied". To fix it, check that the local system account has permission to delete that folder. You can do it from the command line using "cacls". LocalSystem should have access by default, as a member of the Administrators group, but that may have been removed. If it is missing, take ownership of the folder first.

Another problem might be that the folder is "in use", that is a handle is open with deny delete set for sharing. This is harder to solve. You may need to log the user off first or wait then retry.

Comment: In this case, the "access denied" occurs because you're not allowed to do certain file-specific operations (including DeleteFile) on a directory.

Comment: Yes, you are very correct. Mental note: do not answer Stack Overflow questions at 1am in the morning. You miss simple stuff.

Comment: Thank you. Microsoft supply some specific functions on Directory. I run the application as System service, the LocalSystem account.